# ExecuteSprocAccessor does not function for CUD operations?

Tags: enterprise-library

I have several stored procedures in my database. For example a delete stored procedure like:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[DeleteFactor]
@Id uniqueidentifier
as
begin
    delete from Factors where Id = @Id
end
```

When I call this from code like this:

```
dc.ExecuteSprocAccessor("DeleteFactor", id);
```

then the row does not get deleted. However this code functions:

```
dc.ExecuteNonQuery("DeleteFactor", id);
```

`id` is a passed in parameter and of type Guid.

Can anyone explain why the second does work and the first approach does not? I find it quite strange as the first method is clearly to be used with stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Retrieving Data as Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664742%28PandP.50%29.aspx), the `ExecuteSprocAccessor` method uses deferred execution (ala LINQ).  So, in the first approach, since you are not accessing the results of the DeleteFactor stored procedure the SQL call is not being made.

I would use the second method anyway since you really are executing a non-query.  Also, the first approach may lead to some confusion since the `ExecuteSprocAccessor` is designed to retrieve data. e.g. "Is data supposed to be returned here?  Maybe something was missed?"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Perhaps the naming of that method should be revised to something like ExecuteSprocAccessorForRetrievingData

Answer (score 0):

Just call `ToArray` or `ToList` on the result of your `ExecuteSprocAccessor` to make it execute.